# Spring Boot H2 create log table with many-to-many relationship to other table

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have a table Account, which contains info about clients accounts. I want to create a log table (containing sender and recipient fields), and every time when a request is sent to server (e.g. there was a transfer between two accounts) I want to insert info about this operation to this table.

So I supose I need to create many-to-many relationship between Account and Log table. But what joins do I need then? The sender and recipient fields in Log table have to be objects of Account class. How can I map them with Spring JPA annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the follow code to solve your problem.
Firstly, you must define the `Account` class in this way:

```java
@Entity
public class Account{
   @GeneratedValue
   @Id
   private long id;
   //others fields bellow 
}
```

and then you can create a new `Log` class who it has two field with the recipient and sender and both has `@ManyToOne` relationship like this:

```java
@Entity
public class LogAccountTransference{
    @GenerateValue
    @Id
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Account recipient;
    @ManyToOne
    private Account sender;
    //others field about Log Table

}
```

If you still will have some question just tell me.